# Calculating the momentum - notation issue

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

The question is more about notation than physics, so I'll ask it here.

We know that velocity $v$ is an integral of acceleration: $v(t)=\int a(t)dt$

Momentum is $p=mv$. I'd like to derive the formula for $\Delta p$ (the change of momentum in time).

$\Delta p=m(v_2 - v_1)=m(v(t_2) - v(t_1)) = m(\int a(t_2)dt_2 - \int a(t_1)dt_1)$.

We know that $\int a(t)dt = A(t) + C$ such that $A'(t)=a(t)$. Here, the constant $C$ in both integrals $\int a(t_2)dt_2$ and $\int a(t_1)dt_1$ will be the same (equal to the velocity of the object at time $0$), so their difference is $A(t_2)-A(t_1) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(t)dt.$

$\Delta p=m(\int a(t_2)dt_2 - \int a(t_1)dt_1) = m\int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(t)dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}ma(t)dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}F(t)dt$.

(because force $F=ma$)

Is this correct? Should I change anything in this notation?

Comment: Indefinite integrals in physics are a slippery slope. Try to avoid them if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We know that velocity $v$ is an integral of acceleration: $v(t)=\int
>  a(t)dt$

More precise it is
$$
v(t) - v(t_0) = \int\limits_{t_0}^t a(\tau) \, d\tau
$$

> Momentum is $p=mv$. I'd like to derive the formula for $\Delta p$ (the
>   change of momentum in time).
>
> $\Delta p=m(v_2 - v_1)=m(v(t_2) - v(t_1)) = m(\int a(t_2)dt_2 - \int
>  a(t_1)dt_1)$.

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta p
&= m(v_2 - v_1) \\
&= m(v(t_2) - v(t_1)) \\
&= 
m \left(
v(t_0) + 
\int\limits_{t_0}^{t_2} a(\tau) \, d\tau - 
v(t_0) - \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_1} a(\tau) \, d\tau 
\right) \\
&= m \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} a(\tau) \, d\tau \\
&= \int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2} F(\tau) \, d\tau
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So statement 'velocity is integral of acceleration over time' is wrong, instead we should say the change of velocity is integral of acceleration over time, right?

Comment: It is used with usual sloppyness regarding the constants of integration. That statement came from integrating $dv = a \, dt$ regarding $dt$. The other way round, acceleration is the time derivative of velocity, you circumvent that introduction of a constant of integration.